# Vim: Warn if file is not tracked in Git

Tags: git, vim

[Gitgutter](https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter) is great tool for keeping me informed about uncommitted changes but too often I forget full files from commits.

I'd like to have a warning in the Vim statusbar if I'm editing a file that's in a git repository directory but completely untracked.

Any ideas how to implement this?

I'm currently using [Airline](https://github.com/bling/vim-airline#) and [Fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) so it would be nice if it could implemented with those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, define a function something like this:

```
fun! GitTracks(...)
  let file = a:0 ? a:1 : expand('%')
  let message = system('git ls-files -- ' . file)
  let is_tracked = (message =~ '^fatal:') ? 0 : strlen(message)
  if is_tracked
    hi StatusLine guibg=blue
  else
    hi StatusLine guibg=black
  endif
  return is_tracked
endfun
```

This will return 0 if you are not in a git repository or if your file is not tracked.  Who knows, some day you may want to call it with an argument.  Just for kicks, I change the color of the status line.  (This takes a while to kick in, depending on your setting for `'updatetime'`.  You could remove it from the function and use a `BufEnter` autocommand that checks the value of `GitTracks()`.)

Next, decide how you want to indicate this in your status line.  For example,

```
:set stl+=%{GitTracks()?'tracked':'NOT\ tracked'}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! Here's what I did with airline https://github.com/epeli/vimconfig/commit/dc7fdc6f79b4ddf81e1685c875105d010002f0b4

Comment: Actually I had to update it a bit to avoid rendering gliches https://github.com/epeli/vimconfig/blob/23d97ae6d668b22f3da56a5373744c9f579d117d/vimrc#L149-L164

Answer (score 0):

You can almost certainly do this with [powerline](https://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline). It's a hugely configurable utility that can be used in vim to give you a really powerful statusline, as well as in bash/zsh for powerful prompt display.

Here's what mine looks like (stock configuration), showing the following info:

{normal mode active} | BR: {current git branch} | {filename}
[image: vim-powerline-example]

I'm certain there'll be a way to get status for the current buffer's file in there...

Answer (score 0):

If you use the git [fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) plugin it's easy to setup on the statusline. Just add the following to your .vimrc file.

```
set statusline=%f
set statusline+=%{fugitive#statusline()}
```

Of course you can get as fancy as wish. http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/17.html

Comment: fugitive#statusline() does not print the file tracking status. Only branch afaik.